How to properly interrupt a Readable stream before end using async iterators
Node.js v20
I have a Readable stream obtained from a call to a database. I am creating an async iterator from this stream, but I don't want to iterate all the data. If a certain condition is true, I want to interrupt reading data from the stream before the stream has reached the end. The problem is that I am always getting an AbortError or a ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE error if I call stream.end() manually:
import {pipeline} from 'stream/promises';
import {createWriteStream} from 'fs';

async function* myGenerator() {
    const stream = await someCalltoDb();

    stream.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('[STREAM ERROR]', err);
    });

    let stop = false;

    for await (const rows of stream) {
        for (const row of rows) {
            const jsonRow = await row.json();

            if (condition) {
                stop = true;
                // stream.end(); // --> This causes ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE instead
                break;
            }

            yield jsonRow;      
        }

        if (stop) {         
            break;
        }

    }
}

(async () => {
    const iterator = myGenerator();
    const outputStream = createWriteStream('output.txt');
    await pipeline(iterator, outputStream);
})();


What is the correct way of partially consume a stream in an async iterator?

I'm not sure about a better way but the error is expected and can be conditionally suppressed with err.name === 'AbortError'

When the condition is met, destroy the readable stream and return from your generator: if (condition) return stream.destroy();
